# Export Custom Object Schema

Tags: custom-object, schema

I am building an app exchange app and I want to transfer orders into a custom Salesforce object called invoice. How can I export the custom object, without any data, into another user's Salesforce? I have a developer edition of Salesforce.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create either a managed or unmanaged package with the custom object in it. Then install that package in the target org. Unmanaged is good if you just want a one off transfer of metadata with no upgrade path. A managed package will give you an upgrade path for most components, but will also lock other components into their current configuration.

See [Understanding Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm)

The alternative is to use the Metadata API to export the schema and then import it again. There are a number of developer tools that support this. The [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) is one of them.